# SQL Server trigger and transaction issue

Tags: sql-server, triggers, transactions

I have a stored procedure which runs and inserts into 10 separate tables. On the very first table I have an "After insert" trigger. However the stored procedure is wrapped in a transaction and is only committed once it has inserted into all 10 tables.

My question is would my trigger only fire once the stored procedure has been committed? Currently I am experiencing issues whereby the record is inserted via asp.net application fine, but the trigger has not fired (the trigger just captures what row was inserted)

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trProductAllergenUpdate]
ON [dbo].[ProductAllergen]
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO AUDIT_PRODUCT (ProductID, Portal_Table, Portal_Column, AuditDescription, UpdateDateTime, OldValue, NewValue)
        SELECT 
            I.ProductID, 'ProductAllergen', 'AllergenStatusID', 
            'Allergen - ' + AT.AllergenType, Getdate(), 
            AS2.AllergenStatus, AS1.AllergenStatus
        FROM 
            Inserted I 
        INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT PA2.* 
             FROM ProductAllergen PA2
             INNER JOIN
                 (SELECT 
                      ProductID, AllergenTypeID, MAX(productAllergenID) [ProductAllergenID]
                  FROM ProductAllergen
                  WHERE isLive = 0 
                  GROUP BY ProductID, AllergenTypeID) X ON PA2.ProductAllergenID = X.ProductAllergenID  
            ) OLD ON OLD.ProductID = I.ProductID 
                  AND OLD.AllergenTypeID = I.AllergenTypeID
        INNER JOIN 
            ProductAllergen NEW ON NEW.ProductID = OLD.ProductID 
                                AND NEW.AllergenTypeID = OLD.AllergenTypeID
        INNER JOIN 
            AllergenType AT ON I.AllergenTypeID = AT.AllergenTypeID
        INNER JOIN 
            AllergenStatus AS1 ON NEW.AllergenStatusID = AS1.AllergenStatusID
        INNER JOIN 
            AllergenStatus AS2 ON OLD.AllergenStatusID = AS2.AllergenStatusID
        WHERE 
            New.isLive = 1
            AND OLD.AllergenStatusID <> NEW.AllergenStatusID
END
```

Comment: SQL Server triggers fire per statement, not transaction.  If the trigger does not seem to fire, either it is disabled or there is a code problem in the trigger, in which case you should post the trigger code.

Comment: I have added the trigger code. this works fine when I insert directly to the table. but via application it doesn't sometimes work

Comment: Since the `SELECT` statement includes joins, could it be that not all rows on those other tables are yet inserted when the `INSERT ProductAllergen` is executed during the transaction?

Comment: I'm with Mr. Guzman. Your join is an inner join and the inserted rows must match the other tables for the data to be inserted. Your test data matches and your 'real life' inserts from your app is producing rows that don't match. Try inserting, through the trigger, into a table with noting but the rows from inserted. They will all be inserted by the trigger.

Comment: so if I have a statement which inserts the rows from inserted table into another table first. and then I use the join on the new table (e.g Inserted2 table) this should resolve it?